# Delete cookie if another cookie is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a requirement where I need to display different content if a customer enters our website through an ad, based on the last ad they clicked on..  If they click ad A, we want to show banner A, and set a cookie so this banner will display for 24 hours after their click.  However, if they click ad B during that 24 hours, we want to show them banner B for 24 hours and not banner A.  and then if they click again on ad A, show banner A. If they have not clicked on any ad, we want to show them banner C.

My approach for achieving this is to set a cookie dependent on the ad they clicked, and if they click the OTHER ad while that cookie is present, delete the first cookie and create the corresponding cookie for the ad.  Hope this makes sense so far.

I have written a function to look for these cookies and display the corresponding content, but only the first one works.   The cookies are being set for both ad scenarios, but the adroll cookie is not deleted if PPC cookie is present.  The PPC cookie IS deleted if adroll is present.  Where have I gone wrong? Here is all the code in the script tag. Also, the site this is for uses jQuery 1.3.2 without the chance of upgrading, fyi.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("utm_source=adroll") > -1)) {
        var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
        var adRollexpire = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
        document.cookie = "adroll=true;expires=" + adRollexpire.toUTCString();
    }

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("source=bing") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("source=google") != -1) {
        var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
        var PPCexpire = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
        document.cookie = "ppc=true;expires=" + PPCexpire.toUTCString();
    }

    $(function() {
        var delete_cookie = function(name) {
            document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        };

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('adroll=true') >= 0) {
            delete_cookie('ppc=true');
            $("#adRDetails").show();
            $("#adRDetails").click(function() {
                $("#adRollDetailsBox").show();
            });
            $(".close").click(function() {
                $("#adRollDetailsBox").hide();
            });
        }
        else if (document.cookie.indexOf('ppc=true') >= 0) {
            delete_cookie('adroll=true');
            $("#ppcDetails").show();
            $("#ppcDetails").click(function() {
                $("#ppcDetailsBox").show();
            });

            $(".close").click(function() {
                $("#ppcDetailsBox").hide();
            });
        }

        else {
            $("#gwp-banner").show();
            $("#cuisinetowelDetails").click(function() {
                $("#cuisinetoweldetailsBox").show();
            });
            $("#cuisinetowelclose").click(function() {
                $("#cuisinetoweldetailsBox").hide();
            });
        }

    });
});
```

If anyone has any alternative methods to achieve this goal, I am open to other methods as well.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm just wondering why PPCexpire is highlighted whereas adRollexpire is not, but I can't see how this could be related to the problem.

Comment: yeah, i hadn't noticed that! weird. caps?

Comment: @Igle I think the editor assumes a leading uppercase letter means a class name.

Answer (score 0):

If PPC cookie is set, and then the user comes in through adroll, it looks like the first thing you do is create the adroll cookie - and THEN you check which cookies are there (and naturally find both are).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out- i rewrote the logic to delete the unwanted cookie at the time of setting the desired cookie, rather than after the fact in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the code to delete the unwanted cookie when the desired cookie is set solved this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        if ((window.location.href.indexOf("utm_source=adroll") > -1)){
        var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24*1;
        var adRollexpire = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
        document.cookie = "adroll=true;expires=" + adRollexpire.toUTCString();
        document.cookie ='ppc=true; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("source=bing") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("source=google") != -1){
        var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24*1;
        var ppcexpire = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
        document.cookie = "ppc=true;expires=" + ppcexpire.toUTCString();
        document.cookie ='adroll=true; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }

        $(function(){
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('adroll=true') >= 0){
        $("#adRDetails").show();
        $("#adRDetails").click(function() {
        $("#adRollDetailsBox").show();
        });
        $(".close").click(function() {
        $("#adRollDetailsBox").hide();
        });         
        }

        else if (document.cookie.indexOf('ppc=true') >= 0){
        $("#ppcDetails").show();
        $("#ppcDetails").click(function() {
        $("#ppcDetailsBox").show();
        });
        $(".close").click(function() {
        $("#ppcDetailsBox").hide();
        });         
        }

        else {  
        $("#gwp-banner").show();
        $("#cuisinetowelDetails").click(function() {
        $("#cuisinetoweldetailsBox").show();
        });
        $("#cuisinetowelclose").click(function() {
            $("#cuisinetoweldetailsBox").hide();
        });     
        }   
});
        });
```